# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z Spring Boot with Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run my spring boot application with IntelliJ, and I'm using Oracle JDBC
I got always this error :

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z
```

I thought it's a dependency problem, I deleted all .m2 repository and I reimported the project but I get the same error

this my application.properties :

```
server:
  port: 9000
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
    username: me
    password: me
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
  data:
    rest:
      base-path: /api
  liquibase:
    enabled: false
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/changelog-master.yaml
```

this is oracle dependency in my pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Add validationQuery="SELECT 1" to your Data Resource

Comment: I added it but i still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the JDBC version that you want to use. Refer to the [blog](https://medium.com/oracledevs/all-in-and-new-groupids-oracle-jdbc-drivers-on-maven-central-a76d545954c6) for more details.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
  <version> 19.3.0.0 </version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```